# number var not sent to parent component : React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this is parent:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import FilterProps from "./FilterProps";
const Filter: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
    const filtersAllOptions = ["تاریخ", "تگ", "اعضا", "اولویت"];
    const tagOptions = ["درس", "کار", "پروژه", "تیم"];
    const [filterPropsList, setFilterPropsList] = useState<
        { id: number; component: JSX.Element }[]
    >([]);
    const [nextId, setNextId] = useState(0);
    const [childData, setChildData] = useState(0);

    const handleChildClick = (id: number) => {
        setChildData(id);
        console.log(childData);
        handleDeleteFilter(childData);
    };

    const handleAddFilterClick = () => {
        const newFilterPropsList = [...filterPropsList];
        // const id = nextId;
        console.log("last added id: " + nextId);
        newFilterPropsList.push({
            id: nextId,
            component: (
                <FilterProps
                    id={nextId}
                    _allOptions1={filtersAllOptions}
                    _allOptions2={tagOptions}
                    onDelete={handleChildClick}
                />
            ),
        });
        setFilterPropsList(newFilterPropsList);
        setNextId(nextId + 1);
    };

    const handleDeleteFilter = (id: number) => {
        console.log(id);
        const newFilterPropsList = filterPropsList.filter(
            (filterProps) => filterProps.id !== id
        );
        setFilterPropsList(newFilterPropsList);
    };
    return (
        <div className="container210">
            <div className="filterTitleLayout">
                <span className="text210">فیلترها</span>
                <img
                    src="../../assets/img/black-exit-icon.png"
                    className="cursor-pointer"
                    alt="x"
                />
            </div>
            {filterPropsList.map((filterProps) => (
                <React.Fragment key={filterProps.id}>
                    {filterProps.component}
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
            {/* <FilterProps
                _allOptions1={filtersAllOptions}
                _allOptions2={tagOptions}
            ></FilterProps> */}
            <button className="addNewFilterText" onClick={handleAddFilterClick}>
                افزودن فیلتر جدید
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Filter;
```

this is children:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SearchableSelect from "../../ShareComponent/SearchableSelect";
import "./style.css";

interface ISearchableProps {
    id: number;
    _allOptions1: Array<string>;
    _allOptions2: Array<string>;
    onDelete: (id: number) => void;
}

const FilterProps: React.FC<ISearchableProps> = ({
    id,
    _allOptions1,
    _allOptions2,
    onDelete,
}): JSX.Element => {
    const handleDelete = () => {
        console.log(id);
        onDelete(id);
    };

    return (
        <div className="FiltersLayout">
            <span className="textInFilterRowInfo1">تسک هایی که</span>
            <SearchableSelect
                _label="نوع فیلتر"
                _allOptions={_allOptions1}
                _placeHolder="جستجو"
            ></SearchableSelect>
            {/* <select className="tagPickerLayout cursor-pointer">
                    <option value="1"></option>
                    <option value="2">درس</option>
                </select> */}
            <span className="textInFilterRowInfo1">آن ها</span>
            <SearchableSelect
                _label="فیلتر"
                _allOptions={_allOptions2}
                _placeHolder="جستجو"
            ></SearchableSelect>
            <select className="tagPickerLayout cursor-pointer my-auto">
                <option value="1">است</option>
                <option value="2">نیست</option>
            </select>
            <img
                src="../../assets/img/trash-bin-icon.png"
                className="my-auto cursor-pointer"
                alt="delete icon"
                onClick={handleDelete}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default FilterProps;
```

in this code: first the id generated and send to children.
and then when delete icon clicked the id passed to parent.
the problem is id not sent to parent.

how to send the id of child component to parent?
i want to use this id to delete it from parent dynamically.
if there is a better way to do this please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: @Konrad i don't think so. if you sure that the problem is that please describe more